# Cannot use same application for REST call what i have exposed for SOAP service in spring boot

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot, soap, microservices

I am trying to create a microservice using spring boot where it will expose REST service. But inside i also want to consume SOAP service. i have created one SOAP service in spring boot  but i also i want to use the same application for my REST calls which i am not able to do. When i am hitting the base url, i can clearly see my SOAP service has been exposed correctly. But when i am hitting to a configured request mapping URI, it is failing to reach. I am very little understanding.. but i need your help to get the idea where i am missing big. Thanks in advance.

Please refer to the below screenshots

Working

[image: working]

Rest call mapping

[image: Rest call mapping]

Not working

[image: not working]

Comment: Please type your code into your post using Markdown formatting, instead of taking a screenshot of the code. Thanks.

Comment: would you please include @EnableWs config class code?

Answer (score 0):

Though your question lacks many vital informations, I would like to give it a shot.
How does your application.properties look like? Which spring boot version are you using?
If you are on latest spring boot, you can try adding 
`server.servlet.context-path=/demo` to your `/resources/application.properties` file. That might be the missing piece here.

Comment: yes i know i haven't provided much info.. sorry for that.. i am only learning these things recently.i am using spring boot 2.0.5 i have used the context-path property into application.property file but didn't work.
My doubt is as intially i created the project to expose a soap webservice..somewhere unknowingly some configuration i have made.. for which all the urls i hit.. the application 
assumes it to be a soap endpoint.. and therefore it is throwing this no service found error. what i want is.. i will expose rest urls and when it gets invoked..internally i will consume soap response .